# Rails: Postgres JSONB "between" query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with Rails 5 + Postgres.

I have a Postgres JSONB column named `data` with data that looks something like:

```
{username: 'McGruff', timestamp: 123456789}
```

I would like to query for data that is **between** two timestamps, to get a subset of records that all have a timestamp within some range (say, the last 24 hours).

Using comments from below, the answer is:

```rb
Model.where("(data->'timestamp')::int BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Executive summary of the duplicate: `->` gives you a `jsonb` value, not a string or integer; `->>` gives you a string back, then cast that string to an integer to get the right comparison logic: `(data->>'timestamp')::int between ? and ?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **where** clause by providing `start` & `end` inputs as strings. as the data stored in string format in **jsonb** column.

somewhat like below:

```
Model.where((data->>'timestamp')::int between ? and ?, start, end)
```

Comment: (1) `->` yields a `jsonb` value, not a string. (2) Strings-containing-numbers don't compare the same as the numbers themselves.

Comment: Wow, thanks UdAY ... that's embarrassing. Using `where` combined with what @muistooshort said above was the solution: `Model.where((data->>'timestamp')::int between ? and ?, start, end)`